# В Вьетнам или во Вьетнам?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, предлоги

Какой предлог правильно писать в отношении Вьетнама: "в" или "во" ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно ***во Вьетнам***. Название начинается с той же буквы, что и предлог, и наблюдается стечение согласных звуков: мягкого В и йота.

Answer (score 2):

Добавление гласного **о** к предлогу **в** наблюдается [во многих случаях](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/118/%D0%B2_%E2%80%94_%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Если слово после предлога начинается на две согласные буквы, первая из которых **В** или **Ф** , то в речи и на письме используется предлог **ВО**:
*во втором, во вторник, во вчерашнем, во взгляде, во владении, во всяком, **во Вьетнам, во вьюге.***

*Есть женщина

В серебряном Поморье.

Она **во вьюгах** мартовских безгрешна.*
В. Казак

*Война **во Вьетнаме** — один из крупнейших военных конфликтов второй половины XX века...*

С предлогом **во** пишутся похожие названия: Вьедма, Вьенна, Вьентьян, Вьерзон, Вьюны.

**Дополнение**

Вопрос № 250262
Поясните, пожалуйста, с названиями каких городов принято употреблять предлог **ВО** вместо **В**?
Благодарю за ответ.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Предлог во выступает перед формами слов, начинающимися сочетаниями «в, ф + согласный», например: во Владимире.

Comment: Почему тогда в Венгрию. а не во Венгрию.

Comment: В **В**енгрию — слово после предлога начинается с одной согласной "в" (следом идет гласная). В воскресенье; в высокой траве; в вышине; в Вене; в Венеции; в Висле; в вазе.